# jQuery location.reload to happen after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a main problem working with ajax success when I try to reload a web page. In ajax success, I have both `location.reload` and `window.location.hash`. After this location.reload, I need to trigger a click event to open up a closed div.

But unfortunately, its the click event that is triggered first and location reload happens after ajax success. Below is my code.

```
$.ajax({
        url: updatedUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'id=' +  id,
        complete: function() {},
        success: function(data) {
            $('.overlay').hide();
            alert(data.status+': '+data.message);
            location.reload();
            window.location.hash = 'link';
            $('toggle-arrow').trigger('click');
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
});
```

Is there any way to trigger the click after location reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add hash before reload and check the hash on load function for `link`, if it is match than trigger the click event,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash == '#link'){
          $('toggle-arrow').trigger('click');
    }
})


$.ajax({
        url: updatedUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'id=' +  id,
        complete: function() {},
        success: function(data) {
            $('.overlay').hide();
            alert(data.status+': '+data.message);
            window.location.hash = 'link';
            location.reload();            

        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `location.reload()`. if you have to stay on the same page. instead that you can just simply open the  div in the same page in your ajax success:

```
$.ajax({
        url: updatedUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'id=' +  id,
        complete: function() {},
        success: function(data) {
            $('.overlay').hide();
            alert(data.status+': '+data.message);
            $('#YOUR_DIV_ID").show();
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
});
```

Comment: This suggestion really helped me because it also maintains other window states like which input is in focus and css updates.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
setTimeout(function(){
$.ajax({
        url: updatedUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'id=' +  id,
        complete: function() {},
        success: function(data) {
            $('.overlay').hide();
            alert(data.status+': '+data.message);
            location.reload();
            window.location.hash = 'link';
            $('toggle-arrow').trigger('click');
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
});
},500);
```